# Showing Fourier transform of $f$ is in $L_1$

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Given $f\in L^2$, and $f'\in L^2$. I need to show that $\hat{f}$, the Fourier transform of $f$, is in $L^1$. Here's what I have so far:

\begin{align}
\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\hat{f}(\xi)|d\xi &= \int _{|\xi|\leq 1}|\hat{f}(\xi)|d\xi + \int _{|\xi| > 1}|\hat{f}(\xi)|d\xi \\
&= C + \int _{|\xi| > 1}\left|\frac{\hat{f'}(\xi)}{i\xi}\right|d\xi \\
&\leq C + \left(\int _{|\xi| > 1} |\hat{f'}(\xi)| d\xi\right)^{1/2}\left(\int _{|\xi| > 1} \frac{1}{\xi^2} d\xi\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq C + ||\hat{f'}|| \\
&< \infty
\end{align}

And I know $||\hat{f'}||<\infty$ due to Plancherel. However I'm not sure the first integral in the RHS of the first equation does converge, i.e. not sure that the first term is less than some $C<\infty$. But I have a feeling that if I choose to integrate over $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ instead of $[-1,1]$ then I can make the integral arbitrarily small. Am I on the right track?

Comment: By writing $\hat{f}(\xi)$ as $\hat{f}(\xi)\cdot 1$ you can use Holder's inequality on the first integral as well.

Comment: @JoeyZou but then I would have to show that the norm of $\int|\hat{f}|^{1/p}$ converges

Comment: Actually, you would need to show that $\int\limits_{|\xi|\le 1}{|\hat{f}(\xi)|^p}$ converges for some $p$.

Comment: Right, $0\leq p\leq 1$. That's even harder. This all would have been easier if $\hat{f}$ had a $\sup$

Comment: No, you can choose $p\ge 1$ (and I believe the statement of Holder's theorem requires $p\ge 1$). In fact, you can choose $p=2$ :)

Comment: Since $|\xi|\leq 1$ is a set of finite measure use Jenson's inequality to bound the 1 norm in terms of the 2 norm.

Comment: @JoeyZou Oh that's right! Never knew what this inequality actually said.